# Find the value change and the index in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, intersection

I have a large dictionary:

```
exp_dict={0: {'length': 38.63999999999999,

  'line_nm': [['Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Metropolitan_1', 'Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Metropolitan_1', 'Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Metropolitan_1', 'Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Metropolitan_1', 'Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Metropolitan_1', 'Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Metropolitan_1', 'Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Metropolitan_1', 'Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Metropolitan_1'],

   ['Metropolitan_1'],

   ['Metropolitan_1'],

   ['Metropolitan_1', 'Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Metropolitan_1', 'Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Central', 'Hammersmith & City_1'],

   ['Central']]},
1:{'length':100,
   'line_nm':[
            ['Bakerloo'],
            ['Bakerloo'],
            ['Central'],
            ['Central'],
            ['Central'],
            ['Northern'],
            ['Northern'],
            ['Northern']

        ]

    }}
```

I want to find out the value change (intersection) in each 'line_nm' part and their index.

For example, I would like to know for `dict['1']`:

at

```
dict['1']['line_nm'][10]
```

the line_nm changed

```
['Metropolitan_1']
```

which has no intersection with

```
dict['1']['line_nm'][0]
```

and at

```
dict['1']['line_nm'][15]
```

the line_nm is `['Metropolitan_1']` which has no intersection with previous `['Metropolitan_1']` in index 10.

I need to know all the index

Currently I can only see whether there is any change by:

```
for key,value in dict.items():
    if set(value['line_nm'][0]).intersection(*value['line_nm'])==set([]):
        print key,True
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you are trying to do.  do you want to compare the intersection of the elements in your nested lists?  Are you only concerned with the intersection of index 5 with index 0, and index 10 with index 5, for each of your nested dictionaries?

Comment: I want to compare each element in the list, finding the first one (say index=a) not intersection with list[0], then find the next one not intersection with list[index=a].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some thoughts:

- Don't use `dict` as a variable name, because it already exists as a builtin.  Use `dict_` (or another name altogether)
- It's better Python style to include spaces around operators like "==" and "=" (a great resource: [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))
- You would probably benefit from [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) for your use case

The code below greedily iterates through the nested lists in your data structure and outputs a dictionary `d`, where the keys of `d` are the keys of your `dict` and the values of `d` are lists of tuples.  The tuples contain the index of the list value in your nested lists, and the list value itself, based on the parameters outlined in your question.

```
d = {}

for k,v in dict_.items():
    d[k] = []
    ind = v['line_nm'][0]
    for i, j in enumerate(v['line_nm']):
        if not any(x in j for x in ind):            
            d[k].append((i, v['line_nm'][i]))
            ind = v['line_nm'][i]

print d

# output:
# {0: [(10, ['Metropolitan_1'])], 
#  1: [(5,  ['Metropolitan_1']), (10, ['Central', 'Hammersmith & City_1'])]}
```

**EDIT**

The above code yields this output for `exp_dict`:

```
# output:
# {0: [(10, ['Metropolitan_1']), 
#      (15, ['Hammersmith & City_1']), 
#      (18, ['Central'])], 
#  1: [(2,  ['Central']), 
#      (5,  ['Northern'])]}
```

If you just want the relevant indexes, then use this code:

```
d = {}

for k,v in exp_dict.items():
    d[k] = []
    ind = v['line_nm'][0]
    for i, j in enumerate(v['line_nm']):
        if not any(x in j for x in ind): 
            d[k].append(i)
            ind = v['line_nm'][i]

print d

# which outputs the following for exp_dict:
# {0: [10, 15, 18], 
#  1: [2, 5]}
```

Comment: Thanks, would you please revisit my post? I have done some changes, so your code may not work well (it misses the 15 which has the same line with the [0] but not same with [15]). The whole point is if you walk along the ['line_nm'] list, you have to change to a new name, i want to find out the index of changing point.

Comment: My pleasure; thanks for your edits - I've edited my answer, including the output based on your new `exp_dict`.  Happy to be of any further help.

Comment: Thank you for your help~ Can u explain the 'ind' part in the code? How does it work? And if any new change appears (same with one of the old names before), will that work? Sorry for so many questions.

Comment: My pleasure; happy to explain, I just invited you to a chat room so we can keep talking.  No worries about the questions.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I might miss the invitation. How do I start a chat?